Cannot get binary security token for from
I'm traying to connecto to sharepoint from local with jupyter, how ever, I have a issue
Cannot get binary security token for from https://login.microsoftonline.com/extSTS.srf

Using this code
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

username = 'username'
password = 'pass'

site_url = "site"
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("{username}", "{password}"))
web = ctx.web.get().execute_query()
print("Web title: {0}".format(web.properties['Title']))

I don't know why happend this error, I can see the Sharepoint content from web, and using same code to connect to other sharepoint I can see the tittle, any suggestion?
Thank you
I tryed to se, first of all the content of the sharepoint, later, only see the tittle, in both case, same result.
